# Generate decreasing list of integers using python range

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

This is a simple question. I have

```
range(1, 11)[::-1]
```

which gives me

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Is there a 'cleaner' way to generate the above list? With a single function perhaps?

Comment: What's wrong with `range(10,0,-1)`? (`list(range(10,0,-1))`, if you use Python-3.x)

Comment: Nothing :) let me try that again, didn't work earlier for some reason

Comment: I think I was trying to write `range(0, 10, -1)` which did not work.

Comment: Like the slicing syntax `[start:stop:step]`, the built-in `range(start, stop, step)` works with the same parameters.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense :) Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: @DYZ The question isn't necessarily a duplicate, but the link does answer my question :P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use that `range(10, 0, -1)`

Answer (score 4):

Using `numpy` you could do

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(10, 0, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's cleaner but you could also use:

```
reversed(range(1, 11))
```

Comment: It's `reversed` -- The list method is `.reverse` (just like `sorted` vs. `list.sort`)

Comment: either is fine for my case I think :)

Comment: @mgilson true, thank you. I have corrected my misspelling